# Linux At Now Command Call Bash Script with Attribute

Tags: linux, bash

Trying to run this code in a bash script however having no luck as it is failing to run. What it is essentially doing is taking the 3rd attribute from the first bash script `${3:-365}` if that attribute is not found it uses the default of 365 for the number of days to run the command. then it calls the bash script `bash /home/corey/emailSignature/deleteUser.sh ${1}` in which is passes a user-defined variable from the first bash script.

```
at now + ${3:-365} days -f 'bash /home/corey/emailSignature/deleteUser.sh ${1}' &
```

Is anyone able to let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: How exactly is this "failing to run"? Any error messages?

Comment: Make sure you understand the [difference between single and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

Comment: With double quotes I am getting the following error message
**warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
Cannot open input file bash /home/corey/emailSignature/deleteUser.sh name: No such file or directory** however that command runs fine without running it in at now

Comment: Aside: Using `.sh` extensions on executables (vs shell *libraries* meant to be sourced) is not great form. For code intended to be run with `bash` instead of `sh`, doubly so. Generally, UNIX commands don't have extensions -- you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`; this is similar to how when you have a Python *module* it has a `.py` extension, but when Python's setuptools creates an executable wrapper for a `main()` function or other entrypoint in that library, there's no extension at all. See also http://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-f` expects a file to read commands from, but instead of a filename are giving it a command.

Feed the command on stdin instead (and remember to escape your parameter):

```
echo "bash /home/corey/emailSignature/deleteUser.sh ${1@Q}" | at now + ${3:-365} days
```

Comment: Note that with a shell too old to have `${var@Q}`, you'd want to `printf 'bash ... %q' "$1" | at now ...`

Comment: Will this command actually run the bash script or just echo what is within the quotes?

Comment: @MrToast Both. When executed, it'll echo the output and give it to `at` as the command to run. Later, `at` will execute the command, which will run the bash script